# Impulse necessary to desaturate reaction wheel in GEO

Tags: reaction-wheel

I'm sure the answer to this question is, "it depends" but i'm just looking for a rough number
I was reading and typically 0.1N is needed but for how long does this force have to be applied? that is, how much impulse is needed?

Comment: It depends on the moment of inertia and the angular speed of the reaction wheel.

Comment: @Uwe can you suggest some approximate time? 1ms? 1s? 10s?

Comment: Please don't ask the exact same question again after it has been closed as needing improvement. Fix the original question instead by editing it.

Comment: To suggest an approximate time I would need to know  the moment of inertia and the angular speed of the reaction wheel.